Number of partitions of (a,b) into k distinct parts which sum up to (a,b)
Problem set
This is somewhat a generalization of the famous partition of integer n into k parts.
Given two integers a,b I need to find the number of partitions into k distinct parts that sum up to (a,b). E.g if (a,b)=(4,6) and k=2 we have q(a,b,k)=7 since the following are partitions:

((1, 1) + (3, 5))

((1, 2) + (3, 4))

((1, 3) + (3, 3))

((1, 4) + (3, 2))

((1, 5) + (3, 1))

((2, 1) + (2, 5))

((2, 2) + (2, 4))


Notice that partition ((2, 3) + (2, 3)) is not taken into account since the parts are the same and each partition is counted once (meaning ((2, 2) + (2, 4)) and ((2, 4) + (2, 2)) are one and the same partition.
My solution
class Partition_2D_K_PARTS:
    def __init__(self, a, b, k) -> None:
        self.q_a_b_k = 0 # counts q(a,b,k)
        self.stack_partition = collections.deque() # represent a partition
        self.calculate_partitions_for_single(a, b, k)

    def calculate_partitions_for_single(self, c, d, k):
        if (k==1):
            if (c==0 or d==0):
                return 
            last_part = (c,d)
            second_to_last_part = (1, 0) if not self.stack_partition else self.stack_partition[-1]
            if (second_to_last_part < last_part):
                self.q_a_b_k += 1
                return 
            else:
                return 
        
        second_to_last_part = (1, 0) if not self.stack_partition else self.stack_partition[-1]
        for j in range(second_to_last_part[1] + 1, d+1):
            i = second_to_last_part[0]
            self.stack_partition.append((i, j))
            self.calculate_partitions_for_single(c-i, d-j, k-1)
            self.stack_partition.pop()
        for i in range(second_to_last_part[0] + 1, c+1):
            for j in range(1, d+1):
                self.stack_partition.append((i, j))
                self.calculate_partitions_for_single(c-i, d-j, k-1)
                self.stack_partition.pop()

My question is ...
As you can see my solution is using recursion (which is not very effective). I want to improve the runtime (convert it to iterative solution or something else.) but I don't quite sure how. Also, I don't want to use too much space since I want to use the function on very large numbers. I would like your help and thoughts on this problem.

CodeReview is where “How can I improve this working code?” questions go.

Cross posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/292370/number-of-partitions-of-a-b-into-k-distinct-parts-which-sum-up-to-a-b

@DavisHerring Algorithm questions are not off topic.
